# Devise Rspec tests not passing. Can't figure out why

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

I've got an app in which I'm extending Devise's RegistrationsController to add some of my own functionality, and for some reason, I can't get of my account creation tests to pass. Everything works fine in development, so I'm almost positive it has something to do with the way I'm writing the test, but honestly, I'm willing to try anything at this point. So frustrating.

Here's an excerpt from my test. You'll see it's checking for a new user, but it's not finding one.

```
describe RegistrationsController do
  before :each do
    @request.env['devise.mapping'] = Devise.mappings[:user]
    @new_user = { 'fname' => 'Stizzle',
                  'lname' => 'Mcgizzle',
                  'email' => 'qwerty@example.com',
                  'password' => 'foobar'
                }
  end
  describe "During a regular registration, " do
    it "filling out the fields correctly should create a new user" do
      RegistrationsController.stub(:verify_recaptcha).and_return(true)
        expect do
          post  :create,
          :user => @new_user,
          :recaptcha_response_field => 'foobar',
          'tos-agree' => 'true'
          end.to change(User.all, :count).by(1)
        end
```

And my controller action:

```
def create
  build_resource
  if verify_recaptcha(:model => resource, :message => "The text you entered did not match.  Please try again.") && resource.save
    if resource.active_for_authentication?
      set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_navigational_format?
      sign_in(resource_name, resource)
      respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    else
      set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_navigational_format?
      expire_session_data_after_sign_in!
      respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    end
  else
    clean_up_passwords resource
    render :action => 'new'
  end
end
```

I tried removing the CAPTCHA from the controller just to see if that might be causing some trouble, but it had no effect.

Thoughts?

Comment: will u please post your error message

Comment: No error, the test just isn't passing. It says "expected count to change by 1, but got 0"

Comment: I think you forgot about confirmation password, didn't you?

Comment: @nash Nope, I don't require a password confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

```
RegistrationsController.stub(:verify_recaptcha).and_return(true)
```

This stubs the message `verify_recaptcha` on the RegistrationsController *class*. That won't work, because `create` is called on an *instance* of RegistrationsController.

rspec-rails has the aptly-named helper method `controller` for this very purpose:

```
controller.stub(:verify_recaptcha) { true }
```

Comment: Made this change, but unfortunately, Recaptcha doesn't seem to be the problem. As I mentioned, I even tried removing the Recaptcha verification from RegistrationsController altogether, but still no dice.

Comment: Can you edit the question to show code which is failing after you made the change? Also, does log/test.log indicate that the save is failing?